# What is difference and similarities between Angular.js/D3.js/Node.js

Tags: node.js, angularjs, d3.js, javascript-framework

I am trying to explore javascript frameworks and I came across these popular frameworks

- Angular.js
- Node.js
- D3.js

I tried to google it, but found very few comparisons.  So can anyone explain actual difference and similarities between them?

Comment: It's like asking to compare refrigerator to washing machine

Comment: @JacekKolasa how would you start that comparison?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You haven't found comparison because they don't have the same purposes. You can actually use both of them in a website.

- Node.js is server-side language based on V8 that allows you to write a whole backend in JS instead of Ruby, Python, PHP or ASP.NET.
- Angular.js is a frontend framework that allows you to make dynamic web application in javascript in the browser.
- d3.js is to create visualizations such as graphs or charts in the browser.

For instance, I created a node.js backend, and one part serves and angular.js application that could use d3.js to make charts. The only similarity is that they rely on Javascript.

Answer (score 1):

- Angular.js: A framework for writing web applications.
- Node.js: JavaScript as a server-side language, mainly used for the server side of real-time web applications.
- D3: Create visualizations like graphs, charts and maps.

What do you need a JavaScript framework for? What do you want to build? Maybe we can give suggestions.